# From 90 to 1 degree angle using only bisect and trisect operations

Tags: geometry

How can we construct an angle of 1 degree starting with a right angle, using only the operations of bisecting or trisecting an angle?

Comment: You can't.  $90 = 2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$.  If you bisect once, then trisect twice, you'll end up with a $5^\circ$ angle.  You can neither bisect nor trisect that to get a $1^\circ$ angle.

Comment: The prime decomposition of $90=2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$ further implies that no sequence of bisecting, trisecting, or taking sums and differences will work either.  I know there is a theorem somewhere but I'm unable to remember the name.

Comment: A sketch to a proof: We wish to construct the number $\frac{1}{90}$ having started with $1$ and using other constructible numbers.  We recursively build our list of constructible numbers by applying one of the following operations: multiply an earlier constructed constructible number by $\frac{1}{2}$, multiply an earlier constructed constructible number by $\frac{1}{3}$, add two earlier constructed constructible numbers together, subtract two earlier constructed constructible numbers together.  The claim is, the only numbers possible to construct then are of the form $\frac{n}{2^a3^b}$.

Comment: Proceeding by induction, supposing we have created some list so far of constructible numbers and they are all of the form $\frac{n}{2^a3^b}$ (*with $n$ an integer*), multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ maintain that property.  Subtracting or adding one to another will have you reach a common demoninator for them which will again be of the form $2^a3^b$.  Thus no finite number of these steps will allow you to construct the fraction $\frac{1}{90}$ as it is instead of the form $\frac{n}{2^a3^b5^c}$ with $c> 0$.

Comment: By using prime decomposition of integers to model this problem, it seems an implicit assumption here is that the angles generated by bisection and trisection are (only) integers. But we can get 2.5 degree angle, for example by bisecting 5 degree angle. Could there be a solution to get a 1 degree angle by somehow combining such factional ones?

Comment: @brad_tx I made no such assumption.  Notice that my work was trying to go from $1$ to $\frac{1}{90}$.  Any such sequence that takes us from $1$ to $\frac{1}{90}$ could also be used to go from $90$ to $1$ and vice versa.  Since it doesn't work for the one, neither can it work for the other.  You could if you wanted rephrase my earlier sketch to a proof and use $90$ as the initial constructible number instead of $1$, leading you to learn that the only constructible numbers then would be of the form $\frac{5^a\cdot n}{2^b3^c}$ with $a,b,c$ non-negative integers, $n$ an integer, and $a\geq 1$.

Comment: On the other hand, since a $72^\circ$ angle can be constructed with straightedge and compass, you could construct a $1^\circ$ angle using straightedge, compass, and trisector.

Answer (score 0):

Bisecting an angle $\alpha$ produces a new angle $2^{-1}\alpha$; trisecting an angle $\beta$ produces a new angle $3^{-1}\beta$.

We can bisect and/or trisect an angle of measure $90^\circ$ until we produce a new angle of measure $1^\circ$ if and only if there exist whole numbers $n$ and $k$ such that

$$\begin{align}
1 &= 90\cdot2^{-n}\cdot3^{-k} \\
2^n\cdot3^k &= 90 \\
2^n\cdot3^k &= 2\cdot3^2\cdot5 \\
\end{align}$$

Thus it is not possible!

Comment: This proof shows that starting from 90, any combination of bisections and trisections will not produce an end result of 1. Does it also show that any sum/difference of the angles that can be produced by a combination of bisections and trisections can't be equal to 1?

Comment: @brad_tx “sum/difference of the angles that can be produced by a combination of bisections and trisections” starting from what angle? It all depends on what angle you can actually draw. We can all start at $180^\circ$.

Comment: Let me say this: using only a straightedge and compass, you can only start with $180^\circ$, which you can bisect to get to $90^\circ$, and then this proof applies.